# Combine lapply and gsub to replace a list of values for another list of values

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I am currently looking for a way to simplify searching through a column within a dataframe for a vector of values and replacing each of of those values with another value (also contained within a separate vector). I can run a for loop for this, but it must be possible within the apply family, I'm just not seeing it yet. Very new to using the apply family and could use help.

So far, I've been able to have it replace all instances of the first value in my vector with the new first value in the new vector, it just isn't iterating past the first level. I hope this makes sense. Here is the code I have:

```
#standardize tank location
old_tank_list <-  c("7.C.4","7.C.5","7.C.6","7.C.7","7.C.8","7.C.9","7.C.10","7.C.11")
new_tank_list <- c("7.B.3-4","7.C.3-4","7.C.1-2","7.C.5-6","7.C.7-8","7.C.9-10","7.E.9-10","7.C.11-12")


sapply(df_growth$Tank,function(y) gsub(old_tank_list,std_tank_list,y))
```

Tank is the name of the column I am trying to replace all of these values within.  I haven't assigned it back yet, because I want to test the functionality first. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Hopefully, this image will help. The photo on the left is the column before my function is applied. The column on the right is after. Basically, I just want to batch change text values.

[Before and After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDGNa.png)

Comment: What is your expected output? Maybe add a sample of the dataset and what it should look like after (personally find it hard to understand what you need as is)?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added a before and after picture of the dataframe. Basically, I'm looking to batch replace text in a column using the apply family.

Comment: Thanks, please just `print(head(df,n))` for both and copy and paste it as a code chunk not image.

Comment: So for the vectors in the question, just replace old_tank with new_tank in the  tank column?

Comment: Yes. the old tank vector contains strings I want to remove from the column. In the same order i would like to replace each one with the values in new_tank vector. So every instance of "7.C.4" is replaced with "7.B.3-4". Then every instance of "7.C.5" is replaced with "7.C.3-4" so on and so forth. I was really hoping to use the apply functions since I'm new to them and it seems like anywhere I can write a for loop, I can use the apply functions.

Comment: Try this: `Map(function(x, y) gsub(x, y,df$Tank), old_tank_list, new_tank_list)`? Can't test. Can also use `mapply` (just a non-list return of `Map` ).

Comment: @NelsonGon this was an interesting solution, but not quite there. It creates a list of 8 (7.C.4,7.C.5,7.C.6 etc.) each contains a vector of the Tank column values, with only that reference replaced. So in the cast of the 7.C.4 vector, all 7.C.4 are replaced with 7.B.3-4, but all 7.C.5 remain untouched. 
`> Map(function(x, y) gsub(x, y,df_growth$Tank), old_tank_list, new_tank_list) $7.C.4  [1] "7.B.3-4" "7.B.3-4""7.B.3-4""7.C.5" "7.C.5" "7.C.5" "7.C.5" "7.C.5" $7.C.5 [1] "7.C.4""7.C.4""7.C.4" "7.C.3-4" "7.C.3-4" "7.C.3-4""7.C.3-4""7.C.3-4" `
Sorry for the poor attempt at code block. Still new

Comment: @Parfait sorry, the image was a poor attempt at the representation since I don't actually have the solution yet, I just copied another portion of the text. Now I'm realize that probably doesn't help. The vectors I provided are in the order each string value needs to be replaced with.

Comment: @Parfait this is the output of your codeblock, which is also an interesting solution but it seems t be doing something strange:

`> ifelse(df_growth$Tank == old_tank_list, new_tank_list, df_growth$Tank)`
  

`[1] "7.B.3-4"   "8"         "8"         "8"         "8"         "8"         "8"         "8"         "7.B.3-4" `

`"8"         "8"         "8"         "8" `       

`[14] "8"         "8"         "8"         "7.B.3-4"   "8"         "8"         "8"         "9"         "9" `       

`"9"         "9"         "9"         "7.C.3-4"  `

Comment: You do not need sapply or gsub. Use `dplyr::recode`. ie `dplyr::recode(the_old_column, !!!setNames(new_tank_list, old_tank_list))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Tank = recode(Tank, !!!setNames(new_tank_list, old_tank_list)))
```